# ASP.NET - Users have direct control on a Label control: this is safe?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I made a page where something entered in a TextBox, is displayed "as-is" on a Label control

Since i am a beginner, I just made:

```
Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text.ToLower();
```

Is this dangerous?
I tried something but it seems that Label controls only takes text, i i felt confident that is safe

Maybe is dangerous if the user will insert some escape command?

Comment: Why did you use .ToLower()???

Comment: i use .ToLower() to do a compare with another hardcoded string. (don't worry, is not a password/username, it is just a quiz, i lowered the caps to make the input not case-sensitive)

Comment: Not that it really matters but ToUpperInvariant will perform better.

Comment: @Magnetic_Dud Also string.Compare might be useful to you. Read about String.Compare and ToUpperInvariant here- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973919.aspx

Comment: i do an "if (string1==hardcoded_string)"; string.Compare is better/faster?

Comment: @RicahrdOD, Magnetic_dud: You should be using .Equals rather than .Compare: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/30/every-problem-looks-like-a-nail.aspx, and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4411bks.aspx

Comment: @Zhaph - Ben Duguid. That's a good point. Magnetic_dud said that a compare was being performed (in a quiz it might be possible that answers have scores hence the need for a compare). However you are probably right as it looks like the compare is really seeing if two strings are equal, so +1 from me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not do Label1.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(TextBox1.Text.ToLower()); You can [read more about it here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525347.aspx). Not doing that may make you vulnerable to [Cross Site Scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) depending on how your app is configured.

So in answer to is it dangerous- it depends. Though ASP.NET validates user input to exclude HTML/scripts this may be turned off. Better not to take the risk! You can learn about ASP.NET's [request validation feature here](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/request-validation/).

Answer (score 4):

Yes definitely this is. Nothing user enters specifically from public web page should be trusted.

You need to clean anything entered by user before committing it to database or displaying in browser.

At lease HtmlEncode it as suggested by [RichardOD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042605/asp-net-users-have-direct-control-on-a-label-control-this-is-safe/1042622#1042622). You can use [Microsoft's AntiXSS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973813.aspx) library for cleaning user input.

Comment: +1. I was going to add in the Microsoft anti XSS library too, but as you've added it there's now no point.